# List migrations separately but use single migration class

Tags: 7, migrations

I have successfully created a custom migration class which works perfectly but my issue is with the `drush migrate-status` output.

When I execute `drush migrate-status` all the XML files I am attempting to migrate from ( I have over a hundred of them each with the same XML structure ) are all compacted into a single migration of *10,000*. **What I need is for each of my xml files to be listed individually.**

I know I can achieve the individual listing by giving each of my XML file a unique migration class but that is inefficient because the code will be exactly the same in all the classes except for the class names.

Can anyone suggest a solution to help achieve my objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to force a tool to do something it's not supposed to do. The [migration tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools) `drush migrate-status` command only provides a **high-level** overview of the migration batch work associated with a migration (current state, migration source entities found, number of entities, migrated, etc.)

There is `drush migrate-messages` if you're wanting to inspect *individual migrations that may have failed*. But if you're wanting a super-granular, per-entity, view of each migration item then you're probably looking at building your own tool or debugging a migration as it's being processed.